# Sharing Node project with other developers

Tags: node.js, intellij-idea

I'm trying to figure out what is the best way to share a node project with other developers.  I'm using IntelliJ and they I added the IntelliJ plugin for node.  I'd like a way where I can set up the project with all the node_modules set in the packages.json and then they can just run the project with Node.

Is this possible from within the IntelliJ IDE?  It seems like to me, you still need the Node packages set up on your own local machine in order to run any Node code.  If this is the case, is there an easy/good solution to sharing this with other developers so if I create the node project, they pull it down, they can run `npm install` or something like that that'll just pull down everything they need on their local machine to run the project?

Comment: Yeah, that's how it works basically. You put all your dependencies in package.json and others just run npm install. The repo, assuming you're hosting on Guthub, wouldn't contain the bulky node_modules directory, which would be created when they run that npm install command.

Comment: @laggingreflex can you answer my question so i can mark it closed.  thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have the right idea. All your dependencies should be listed in [`package.json`](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json). When you, or someone, runs [`npm install`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install) all those dependencies get downloaded and installed in [`node_modules`](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.1/api/modules.html) directory in your project root. You're not required, and even suggested against checking that directory into your repository. Others must simply clone your project and run `npm install` to which shall recreate the `node_modules` directory with your dependencies installed.